# error : Undefined index: name in Laravel blade template

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a login form in my laravel project and send the user login data in my controller method using ajax. While users successfully logged in I kept the user_name in session `$_SESSION['name]`. But when I try to show that `$_SESSION['name]` in my blade template view it gives error

> local.ERROR: Undefined index: name

**Here is my login controller method**

```
public function signin(LoginFormValidation $request)
{
    $user_password = $request->password;

    $data = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();

    if(Hash::check($user_password, optional($data)->password))
    {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $data->name;

        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

**Here is my blade template view**

```
<ul class="cd-main-nav__list js-signin-modal-trigger">

    <li><a class="cd-main-nav__item cd-main-nav__item--signup" href="#0">{{ $_SESSION['name'] }}</a></li>

</ul>
```

Why the username isn't stored in my session or if it stored why gives the error ?

Comment: print_r($_SESSION); to see its results and check whether session is created or its value are getting stored.

Comment: @Raff if you are using Laravel then why you are not using laravel Auth? If you will use Auth for login then you can access user all information everywhere using `Auth::user()`.

Comment: why you are not using `session library` of laravel? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

Comment: @B.Desai...I have already tried `session(['key' => 'value']);`....But got same result

Comment: @Amanjaura...Data already store...i checked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use laravel session helper function

**Controller**

```
public function signin(LoginFormValidation $request)
{
    $user_password = $request->password;

    $data = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();

    if(Hash::check($user_password, optional($data)->password))
    {
        session()->put('name', $data->name);

        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

**Blade**

```
<ul class="cd-main-nav__list js-signin-modal-trigger">

    <li><a class="cd-main-nav__item cd-main-nav__item--signup" href="#0">{{ session()->get('name') }}</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to start the session.

```
session_start();
```

Recommended way for versions of PHP >= 5.4.0

```
 if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
     session_start();
 }
```

Comment: where to use that ? in the controller ?

Comment: use it in the layout file so that you don't need to add it again and again in the views..or maybe just do that in controller if it's just needed there and pass name as variable to view

Comment: ....one interesting thing is .... I have stored some other data in session in my helper function like `role_id`. They all are shown without any error but this `$_SESSION["username"]` is shows error...Mean if I use `$_SESSION["role_id"]` instead of `$_SESSION["username"]` it shows the result